Why does the umask not change as expected in Ubuntu 24.04?
When I create a directory or a file in my website directory (/var/www) with sFTP on Ubuntu 24.04 the chmod is 775 for directories and 664 for files.
I would like the permissions to be 755 and 644.
I already added umask 022 to ~/.bashrc and did a reboot, but nothing changes. Also adding umask 022 to etc/profile didn't change anything. Then I added umask 022 to /etc/apache2/envvars. But still nothing changes.
How can I set the umask of the user or the group www-data like that, that new directories and files will have chmod 755 and 644.
A umask in SSH gives me the value 0022.
The output of findmnt -T /var/www gives me:
TARGET SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS / /dev/vda1 ext4   rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,commit=30

(1) "When I create a directory or a file" – How exactly do you do this? (2) What is the output of findmnt -T /var/www? Please add information to the question ([edit] it), not in comments.

I found the solution. I edited /etc/login.defs and changed UMASK to 022 and USERGROUPS_ENAB to no. That did it!
